# Poppin Tags - or an idea anyway

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

Why are new Tags not treated like first posts from a new user or suggested edits, but a bit more stringent?

My thought:

If a new tag is created, why does it not go to the review bin for voting by high rep users who can determine their worth on that particular SE site. Say it would take 10 (or more) votes for it to become active. A note to the new tag author would be something like "Thank you for your suggestion of the new tag, it will be placed in front of a panel of SU (or what ever SE site) peers for review if it will be adding value to all members." or something like that.

There it sits until 10 (or whatever number seems correct) deem it having value. Someone at that point should have filled the defanition of the tag as well.

This way, a monthy burning may be less taxing if the things never got past first base to begin with.

Just an idea.

Comment: This sounds more like suggested edits than first posts.

Comment: I guess, I am just thinking they should be heavily reviewed and not just turned loose to be examined later after they have clutter everything up. Good idea?

Comment: If the tag gets created the same time as a post (I.e. not through editing) it'd clutter up the post's history. IMO the review afterwards would probably work fine. Remember, tags can only be created by established users.

Comment: @DanielBeck - Yes, but you only need 300 rep to create. I just see the monthly note here on meta about tags that got to go. I am sure there is a better idea than mine out there and would save a bunch of headache for whomever has to clean them up. ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8149/raise-the-minimum-rep-needed-to-create-new-tags